# Read in contents of .h file stored in core data

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data, header-files

A while ago I developed an augmented reality app based on the Vuforia platform. I'm now modifying and expanding it to include many more models by using a core data database that syncs with a web server.

Currently the app uses .h files stored in the app bundle (dragged into xcode) to store model data (screenshot of a header file (eg Rug.h) stored in the app bundle shown below). The .h file defines float and unsigned int arrays that the app uses. I use an `#import "Rug.h"` statement in my code to get access to the data in the file and can then use the arrays to set up the model objects (eg `3DObject.vertices = rugVerts;`.

[image: Screenshot of a header file stored in the app bundle.]

Instead of doing it this way, I need to store the .h file in core data (there will be many .h files now). What's the best way of reading the file in from core data and getting the information out? Do I have to read the entire file in as a string, pluck out the ranges of numbers I want, and convert to numbers for use in my app? Sounds painful.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you need to store them as ".h" files? Why don't you store them as either binary data, or at least something easily parseable like XML or even just CSV?

Comment: This precedent has been set by others. One comment: "Apple recommends that 3D objects be stored in header files as static arrays. This obviates the need to do any loading or transforming or conversion at all."  I could cobble something together if i could store and retrieve the static arrays as NSObjects in core data, but would prefer to store the entire header files and access the arrays in them.

Comment: I think you've misunderstood the comment (or the person who wrote it did). What that comment means is that you should compile them in the source if possible. Not that you should include the header file in your bundle and load it at run time!

Comment: I see what you mean now. I could store in core data as CSV. It's a bit of extra work per model to convert from .h, but at least it would get me back up and running. Thanks.